# (xampp zend framework2) server responded with a status of 500 ()

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, apache2, http-status-code-500

I have Xampp on windows, i'm working with zend framwork 2.
I have this error : localhost is currently unable to handle this request. http error 500
When i delete the code of my index.php as above and i put any think, it works, but when i let the above code, the problem still exist.

index.php:

```
<?php
chdir(dirname(__DIR__));
error_reporting(0);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
// Decline static file requests back to the PHP built-in webserver
if (php_sapi_name() === 'cli-server') {
    $path = realpath(__DIR__ . parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH));
    if (__FILE__ !== $path && is_file($path)) {
        return false;
    }
    unset($path);
}
// Setup autoloading
require 'init_autoloader.php';

Zend\Mvc\Application::init(require 'config/application.config.php')->run();
```

1-I reinstalled xampp.
2-I setd the variables display_errors: On and error_reporting : E_ALL in my php.ini config file and restarted the server.
3- i changed the access licel of htdocs.

My php \xampp\apache\logs\error.log:

[Tue Apr 20 15:40:34.148107 2021] [core:warn] [pid 3340:tid 480] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Tue Apr 20 15:40:34.201075 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3340:tid 480] AH00455: Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1g PHP/7.4.11 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Apr 20 15:40:34.201075 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3340:tid 480] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC15 Server built: Aug  4 2020 11:50:23
[Tue Apr 20 15:40:34.201075 2021] [core:notice] [pid 3340:tid 480] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Tue Apr 20 15:40:34.204072 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3340:tid 480] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 5296
[Tue Apr 20 15:40:34.920846 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5296:tid 660] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.

the console display eroor :
Failed to load resource:
the server responded with a status of 500 ()

It still see the same error page localhost is currently unable to handle this request. http eror 500. Why?

Comment: Have you checked the error log? Error 500 is a generic message meant for the end user, not the developer. Your PHP error log might contain more information about the cause of the issue.

Comment: @El_Vanja in \xampp\apache\logs\error.log, i have above logs.

Comment: That is the Apache error log, not the PHP error log. Look for an error log in the folder where PHP is installed.

Comment: phpinfo() has error_log in C:\xampp\php\logs\php_error_log, but their is no logs directory in xampp\php, when i open php_err_log from xamp  i have path not found error

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this error, i commented the above lines in index.php file that display errors

error_reporting(0);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);

after that i have other errors with cache